# Is there any way to force a program/software to use system proxy in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, networking, proxy

I am working on a Java project in Intellij Idea (Linux) that needs to access websites through a proxy. I have a personal proxy subscription to use and I can request through it programmatically with something like -

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("PROXY_SERVER", PORT);
String res = Executor.newInstance()
            .auth(proxy, "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD")
            .execute(Request.Get("https://example.com").viaProxy(proxy))
            .returnContent().asString();
System.out.println(res);
```

However, if I use the proxy in the `etc/environment` with `http(s)_proxy` or through ubuntu network proxy from the settings, my browsers and some of the system programs such as - Chrome, Firefox use the proxy while making any requests but Intellij Idea doesn't follow the system proxy. I've tried to set it manually from IDEA settings but it doesn't work. The requests are always going from my current IP. So, I was curious if it is possible to force a software in Linux to use system proxy somehow. I need to mention that, I have tried proxychains but it didn't work, my server wasn't recognized. Any kind of help/suggestion will be appreciated as I have a little or no experience in networking.

Comment: Did you restart the program after you changed the system's proxy settings?

Comment: Yes. I have tried rebooting the system as well.

Comment: Please provide idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.